# Why is GSON not parsing these fields properly? (FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)

Tags: json, gson

I have a JSONArray of JSONObjects that I'm trying to parse with GSON. I'm using `FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`. It's parsing correctly for most fields (so the FieldNamingPolicy is set correct), but I'm getting `null` returned for

```
{
      "image_sq_48x48_url": "url1",
      "image_sq_64x64_url": "url2",
      "image_sq_96x96_url": "url3"
}
```

with field names

```
imageSq48x48Url
imageSq64x64Url
imageSq96x96Url
```

Maybe a better question would be what is the proper camelCase? I have also tried

```
imageSq48X48Url
imageSq48X48url
```

If I map with `@SerializedName("image_sq_96x96_url")` it parses/populates correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately those fieldnames in your JSON don't conform to what Gson looks for using that strategy.

If you create a POJO and serialize it, you can see what the issue is:

```
class MyPojo 
{
    String imageSq48x48Url = "hi";
}
```

The resulting JSON from Gson using that strategy is:

```
{"image_sq48x48_url":"hi"}
```

It doesn't consider/look at numeric digits as leading indicators / start of a "word".

If you rename the field to:

```
String imageSq_48x48Url;
```

It would work with your JSON example and that strategy.

Basically, you either need to create your own class that implements `FieldNamingStrategy` that will handle those JSON fieldnames the way you want, or do what you're doing with the `@SerializedName` annotation.